# pass bash variable as argument to gcc

Tags: c, bash, shell, gcc, compiler-optimization

I aim to pass some variable values to gcc. Here my example:

**command:**

```
gcc -Q -fvpt -fwrapv -fwhole-program --help=optimizers
```

**output:**

```
-fvpt                       [enabled] 
-fwhole-program             [enabled] 
-fwrapv                     [enabled]
```

**and When I run:**

```
var="-fvpt -fwrapv -fwhole-program"; gcc -Q $(var) --help=optimizers
```

**output:**

```
-fvpt                       [disabled] 
-fwhole-program             [disabled] 
-fwrapv                     [disabled]
```

Why it does not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(var)` attempts to execute the command `var` and use its output in the command line. To expand a variable in bash, you would use `$var`

```
var="-fvpt -fwrapv -fwhole-program"; gcc -Q $var --help=optimizers
```

Comment: That's correct, but you could also replace the parenthesis with squiggly brackets `{}`.  `${var}` works just like `$var`.

Answer (score 1):

`var="-fvpt -fwrapv -fwhole-program" && gcc -Q $var --help=optimizers` Should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array, not a flat string, to store multiple options. (For the example, a string works, but it will fail for arguments that themselves contain whitespace, and may fail for options containing pattern metacharacters.)

```
args=(-fvpt -fwrapv -fwhole-program)
gcc -Q "${args[@]}" --help=optimizers
```

Comment: thank you. var="-fvpt -fwrapv -fwhole-program"; gcc -Q $var --help=optimizers  works